# Real time task (periodic task)

Tags: c, pthreads, real-time, semaphore

Good evening everyone,

I'm still learning real-time programming, and I'm trying to synchronize two threads using semaphores, the first thread calculates the sum and returns a value (sum). the sum will be passed as a parameter to the 2nd thread that will use it to calculate an average (this is just an example for manipulating semaphores). my problem now and that the two tasks are not periodic because once the thread returns a result it leaves the loop while and the main() finishes the work !!! now how to make the tasks period ?? thank you for helping me and here is my source code.

```
  #include <stdio.h> 
  #include <stdlib.h> 
  #include <pthread.h> 
  #include <semaphore.h>

   sem_t evt; 

  //first task
  void *tache1(void *arg)
  {

    int j;
    int s=0;

    struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);

    while(1){ 

        printf("first THREADDDDDDDDD \n");

        for(j=0; j<100; j++)
            s= s + j;


        return (void*) s;
        sem_post(&evt);

        sleep(3);

     } 
  }

  //second task

  void *tache2(void *arg){

     int moyenne = 1;
     int sum = *((int*) arg);

     struct timespec time;
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);

     while(3){ 

        sem_wait(&evt);

        printf("second THREADDDDDDDDD \n");
        moyenne= sum/10;

        return(void*)moyenne;

        sleep(2);   

     }  
  }

  int main() 
  { 
         pthread_t th1, th2; 
         int sum;
         int moyenne;

         int status;
         sem_init(&evt, 0,0); 
         printf("start main\n") ; 

         pthread_create(&th1, NULL, tache1, NULL); 
         pthread_join(th1, (void*) &sum); 


          pthread_create(&th2, NULL, tache2, &sum); 
          pthread_join(th2, (void*) &moyenne); 

          printf("the sum in the main is %d.\n", sum);
          printf("AVG %d.\n", moyenne);
          printf("End main\n") ;

          return 0; 
     }
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the code now that it's formatted.  The main issue should be apparent.

Comment: Also, `pthread_create` immediately followed by `pthread_join` means you're not *really* multithreading because you start the thread then wait for it to finish before continuing.

Comment: Yes but when i make "pthread_join" after "pthread_create" the execution will be blocked!!!

Comment: The way you have things written now, `th1` has to finish before you even start `th2`.  That's not multithreading.

Comment: Note also that the `return` statement causes the current function to return immediately.  It doesn't just keep going.

Comment: yes I understand you but can you help me or guide me how should I proceed I am trying to understand the proper functioning of the threads in real time system, can you give me an example of two threads synchronized with semaphores and that one of the two uses the results of another??

Comment: yes I understand you but can you help me or guide me how should I proceed I am trying to understand the proper functioning of the threads in real time system, can you give me an example of two threads synchronized with semaphores and that one of the two uses the results of another

Comment: See my answer.  What you're doing also is not dependent on a real-time system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
pthread_create(&th1, NULL, tache1, NULL); 
pthread_join(th1, (void*) &sum); 

pthread_create(&th2, NULL, tache2, &sum); 
pthread_join(th2, (void*) &moyenne);
```

You start a thread, wait for it to finish, then start another thread, then wait for that to finish.  That's not multithreading.  You want both threads to be active at the same time.

Also, both of your thread functions include a `return` statement with more statements after them.  Once a `return` statement is hit, the entire function returns immediately.  No statements after them are executed.  Note also that you don't need a `while (1)` (or `while (3)`) loop in either of these functions.

The idea behind semaphores (and mutexes) is that multiple threads are running at once, and both thread need to operate on global data so one thread needs to wait for the other thread to do something before it can access the global data.

So make `sum` and `moyenne` global variables, start both threads at once, and get rid of the extra loops in the thread functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t evt;
int sum;
int moyenne;

void *tache1(void *arg)
{
    int j;
    int s=0;

    printf("first THREADDDDDDDDD \n");

    for(j=0; j<100; j++)
        s= s + j;

    sum = s;
    sem_post(&evt);

    return NULL;
}


void *tache2(void *arg)
{
    sem_wait(&evt);

    printf("second THREADDDDDDDDD \n");
    moyenne= sum/10;

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t th1, th2;

    sem_init(&evt, 0,0);
    printf("start main\n") ;

    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, tache1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&th2, NULL, tache2, NULL);

    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);

    printf("the sum in the main is %d.\n", sum);
    printf("AVG %d.\n", moyenne);
    printf("End main\n") ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer .. the question that I have now  is why remove the while ?? according to my knowledge the real time system  , the tasks must be periodics so while in my code is for the periodicity ... can you explain to me this point please !!

Comment: How can I perform the treatment (sum and avg) using two real-time tasks ??

Comment: @ikram You code only calculates the sum and average once, so the threads only need to run once, so no `while` loops needed.